# Chrome Extension: How to block and unblock requests conditionally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to conditionally add and remove a listener for a request block but when I remove the listener i get an infinite loop and the site won't load anmyore. I'm using the storage and a button to set the status to true of false and add the listener when it's true and when it's false it should remove the listener.

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function (changes, namespace) {
  for (var key in changes) {
    var storageChange = changes[key];
    console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
      'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
      key,
      namespace,
      storageChange.oldValue,
      storageChange.newValue);
  }

  chrome.storage.sync.get('status', function (data) {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
      removeJS,
      {
        urls: ["https://devtest.com*"],
        types: ["script"]
      },
      ["blocking"]);

      function removeJS() {
        if (data.status === true) {
          return {
            cancel: true,
          }
        }
      }

      if (data.status === false) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(removeJS);
      }
    });
  });
```

I don't know if I'm referring to the callback correctly. Maybe that could be the problem but I already tried a bunch of solutions.

Comment: 1) Declaring removeJS inside another function makes it a new function object reference each time get() runs so removeListener() won't work as it needs the old reference which you no longer have. You should declare removeJS in the global context so its object reference stays constant. 2) There should be no need for chrome.storage.sync.get as you can use changes.status.newValue directly.